# How to invoke azure easy API using angularjs in VS2013 Cordova Application?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-api

I have created **azure Easy API** on azure App services.How To get the API values from Easy API using angular Js.But now I am struggling To call API.For App services there is no app key i Don't know how to Call API.

Before i have Used Azure mobile services so i can Invoke API easily by following lines.it was easy for me.

```html
 var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
                "https://yourservice.azure-mobile.net/",
                "API KEY");            

            client.invokeApi('commentsapi', {
                method: 'GET'
            }).done(function (response) {
                success(JSON.parse(response));
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the v2.0.0-beta release of azure-mobile-apps-client (available via npm) - copy the MobileServiceClient.min.js to your web area and include it - if you are building the app with webpack or browserify, you can just "require('azure-mobile-apps-client')".

You don't need an API key any more.  Otherwise, your client looks good.

Comment: I have downloaded github project in this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client. i searched for MobileServiceClient.min.Js but downloaded project has only mobileservice.js file.can i include this file into my project? or else Have any cdn link to access the js file directly?

Comment: The .min.js is included in the npm package.